# How to Do Show/hide section based on a Security Role in Dynamics CRM 2013 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

How to show/hide Tabs and Sections based on a User Security Role in Dynamics crm 2013.could you plz anyone clarify that

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be done without development so you have to combine code from following articles:

http://blogs.infinite-x.net/2010/11/16/retreiving-user-roles-in-crm-2011/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328067.aspx#BKMK_tabsetVisible

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_setVisible

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328489.aspx#BKMK_sectionSetVisible